# Define Tuple Types in loop over Map Entries

Tags: typescript, for-loop, types

I had a nice `.forEach` loop going:

```
myMap.forEach((val: object, key: number) => {
    console.log(val)
})
```

And now I want to add a continue statement which requires me to refactor it as a for loop:

```
for (let [key, val] of myMap.entries()) => {
    console.log(key) 
    console.log(val) 
    if (something) continue
}
```

Would someone show me how to define the types for the tuple in the for loop?

This [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Fg0HUiXH8D0Ii8ACIAKKreU1fQ7pI4nfgBwW4QAOQ5O6CKgA8t8yLtBEutJBjqhHApXNIeCgE4Co6KMWD6CgCCIDCwhXNOEihtEIgGBwOLdCwbBcNwQQlEAA) has been helpful.

Comment: The types are already automatically inferred for you by TS. There is no need to add additional type syntax noise to the code. Automatic type inference is sufficient 95% of the time in TS, I've found, and makes the code cleaner.

Comment: @CertainPerformance do you want to post that as an answer? I'm also open to deleting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are already typed correctly, thanks to TypeScript's automatic type inference:

[image]

TypeScript can infer types automatically most of the time, and in such cases, there's no need to explicitly denote the type of a particular identifier.

If you find that iterating over a Map isn't giving you type-useful results, rather than trying to re-define the types properly when iterating over it, instead change the Map's definition. Eg, if you had

```
const myMap = new Map();
```

and then proceeded to add `number` and `{ amount: number }` objects to it *after* the map's initialization, to type it correctly, use generics:

```
const myMap = new Map<number, { amount: number }>();
```